# AndroidManifest.xmlにおける<uses-library>の意味と使い方

Tags: android, gradle

AndroidManifest.xml における `<uses-library>` の意味と使い方はどういったものですか？

Android公式で説明されていますがいまいち理解できません。
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=ja#libs

`<uses-library>` を書かずとも
build.gradle の `dependencies{ ... }` ブロックに `compile 'group:name:version` と書くだけでライブラリを利用することができてしまいます。

Comment: [こちら](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html?hl=ja)の説明の方が理解しやすいかもしれません。Google Playでアプリがフィルタされるかどうかのひとつにも`<uses-library>`が利用されるようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play でアプリのフィルターを利用するために利用されます。 [このドキュメント](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html?hl=ja)の内容を引用しますと

> アプリは、デバイスで動作するために特定の共有ライブラリを要求できます。
>
> 例 1 アプリが com.google.android.maps ライブラリを必要とし、ユーザーが
>   com.google.android.maps ライブラリを持たないデバイスでアプリを検索しています。結果:Google Play
>   はユーザーにアプリを表示しません。

と言うことなので、端末に Google Maps がインストールされていないなどのユーザーにはアプリが表示されなくなります。

gradle に記述をする依存関係はビルドやコードを書くために必要なものですが、 `<uses-library>` はユーザーに対して依存しているサービスを明記するためのものですね。